# why Paypal IPN not returning contact_phone field?

Tags: php, paypal

Sorry for my English.

I am using PayPal sandbox for testing.

I send data to PayPal sandbox .... like item_number

When user made payment, I got details of transaction on my IPN URL.

IPN contain all fields only one **contact_phone** is missing..

Is anyone knows, what exactly is the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`contact_phone` is not in the HTML Variable list according to the documentation. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

You will need to pass it through the optional phone fields (`night_ phone_a`,`night_ phone_b`,`night_ phone_c`), put it in the `custom` field, or as a hack use any other unused field.